# jquery show() doesn't work after setTimeout() method

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I've got a flex slider with 3 div's filled by different amount of content. When a button is clicked all those div's `translateX(-100%)`.

To keep the footer always at the bottom of the visible content I need to hide the content of the previous slide, but to do it only when it leaves the viewport. For that I'm using `setTimeout()`. When the slider reaches the limit of slides everything is translated back to `X(0)`, but I can't understand why my hidden elements don't show up. I guess my eyes are already soaped, please help.

```js
let count = 0;
let services = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article'));

$('#services-prev').on('click', function() {
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
    $('.services-slide').css('transform', `translateX(-${count*100}%)`);
    $('#services-articles article').css('transform', `translateX(-${count*100}%)`);
    $('.services-item', services[count]).show();
  };
});

$('#services-next').on('click', function() {
  if (count < 3) {
    count++;
    $('.services-slide').css('transform', `translateX(-${count*100}%)`);
    $('#services-articles article').css('transform', `translateX(-${count*100}%)`);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.services-item', services[count - 1]).hide()
    }, 500);
  }

  if (count >= 3) {
    $('.services-item').show();
    count = 0;
    //$('.services-slide').appendTo($('.services-slider-container'));
    $('.services-slide').css('transform', `translateX(0)`);
    $('#services-articles article').css('transform', `translateX(0)`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Although I don't fully grasp yet what you want, I do see a potential bug: if you expect the `setTimeout` callback to use the *same* value for `count` as what it was at the time `setTimeout` was initiated, then you have a problem: `count` changes in the mean time. So avoid this by assigning `count` to a local variable before doing `setTimeout` and reference that variable instead of `count` in the callback function.

Comment: I see Your point, thank's for that, but I guess, that is not  quite my problem right now.  What I'm struggling right now is a reason, why my hidden elements, don't show up here:  'if (count >= 3) {
    $('.services-item').show();
    count = 0;
    //$('.services-slide').appendTo($('.services-slider-container'));
    $('.services-slide').css('transform', `translateX(0)`);
    $('#services-articles article').css('transform', `translateX(0)`);
  }'